# UIMA Ruta run errors using DKProCore Part-of-Speech Tagger (German Novels tutorial)

Tags: nlp, uima, ruta, treetagger, dkpro-core

When following [this](http://uima.apache.org/downloads/ruta/tutorial-GermanNovels.pdf) tutorial on UIMA Ruta for German Novels step by step, I get the following error upon running Main.ruta:

```
*SEVERE: Exception occurred
org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException
(...)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to locate model [de] in the 
following locations 
[classpath:/de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/treetagger/lib/tagger-de-
little-endian.par].  Make sure the environment variable 
'TREETAGGER_HOME' or 'TAGDIR' or the system property 'treetagger.home' 
point to the TreeTagger installation directory.*
```

I have verified the location of my TREETAGGER_HOME, which is set in my environment variables and in Eclipse. I also considered using a more recent verison of the treetagger and found the following errors:

**1.7.0**
    *SEVERE: Exception occurred
    org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException: 
    Annotator processing failed. 
    (...)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.parameter.Messages
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 more*

**1.8.0** 
    *SEVERE: Exception occurred
    org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException: 
    "Unsupported language [de]."
    at de.tudarmstadt.uk
    (...)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to load resource 
    [classpath:/de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/treetagger/lib/tagger-de-
    le.properties]: 
    FileNotFoundException: No file found at 
    [classpath:/de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/treetagger/lib/tagger-de-
    le.properties]*

Upon seeing the error in the last attempt I checked once more the language parameters for German which are present under the necessary formats.
Any advice on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the license of TreeTagger prohibits distributing it through Maven Central.

The is a long answer to that which includes how to build and install the TreeTagger models locally. You could look e.g. at the instructions [here](https://github.com/hltfbk/Excitement-Open-Platform/wiki/Step-by-Step,-TreeTagger-Installation) provided by the Excitement project which also uses DKPro Core.

I would recommend you try using another tagger instead of TreeTagger, e.g. the OpenNlpPosTagger from DKPro Core. Instead of the `de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.treetagger-asl` use `de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.opennlp-asl` in the pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.opennlp-asl</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And in the POSTag.ruta script, try replacing the import/exec of `TreeTaggerPosLemmaTT4J` with these:

```
UIMAFIT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.opennlp.OpenNlpPosTagger;
...snip...
Document{-> EXEC(OpenNlpPosTagger, {pos.POS, Lemma})}:
```

Warning: I haven't tried running this ;)

*Disclaimer: I'm working on DKPro Core.*